# Static blocks rendering short code on front end - after whitelisting

Tags: static-block, ce-1.9.2.4

I am hoping someone can offer some advice / direction.  I have a problem with Magento static blocks that I can seem to sort out even after a lot of reading / testing.  I know enough to be dangerous with Magento but not a whole lot more so please forgive any terminology errors.  I will try and explain the best I can ( sorry for the wall of text ).

**The situation.**

- I had a site on 1.9.0.1 and tried an over the top updated to 1.9.2.4 and ran into problems with hangs on processing the order and customer registration that I believe were related to JS issues with an outdated template ( which I did not update initially ).
- I then did a fresh install of 1.9.2.4 to a subdomain, installed the updated ‘compatible’ template and connected up a copy of the original database.
- I updated my template customization (css etc), copied over the media directory and copied across the code for a custom module we had developed that programmatically includes static blocks into products (based on product attributes) in TWO of the top level product categories.  After some issues with finding all the customized code directories (just my lack of knowledge) I got this working, and the checkout and customer registration all working again, products, images etc. all working.
- Initially NONE of the blocks were not working at all on the **over the top upgrade**, but I searched around and worked out the changes with 1.9.2.2 with block whitelisting - and on the over the top upgrade, ALL BLOCKS are working. Both the programmatically and short code included blocks.
- HOWEVER - I have a number of other categories that build their product descriptions through including a number of blocks via short code.  All included via standard short code {{block type="cms/block" block_id=  ….. }} – all are cms/block and include simple html, images etc.  No php, JS etc.  ***This is where the problem starts.***

**So…. The problem.**

- With the **fresh install** and blocks types whitelisted – the programmatically included blocks are working fine, however the short code blocks are failing to render – instead it is actually displaying the full short code on the front end.
- The **over the top upgrade** is working for both programmatically and short code includes, so this leads me to believe it is something to do with the template update, but I just can’t seem to find the problem, and I have been scouring the interwebs with no luck.  It seems others with problems of blocks not displaying are generally to do with whitelisting.
- EDIT: I just tested if {{block...  is working in in CMS pages, and it IS working?

**Some notes.**

- I have tried adding short code to the category description for both types of categories ( ones where blocks are added programmatically and via short code ) and they are not working under either.
- Compilation is disabled, cache constantly cleared and index refreshed every test.
- Logs are turned on and I am getting no errors / warning at all.  I know it is working as there were errors early on that I cleared.
- There are no php error’s showing on the server.
- No errors or warning showing in firebug console.
- Both the over the top install and upgrade are running on the same server ( the upgrade is running under a sub domain ).

I have spent a lot of time searching for solutions, trying different things and learning a lot, however I just can’t seem to work out the ussie, or find posts anywhere others having similar problems.  For all I know there is a simple switch I have failed to throw to allow the rendering of the blocks or something but I have painfully gone over every setting I can find, and everything seems to match between the two sites.  Also, when I implemented this all on the old site, the short code inclusions just worked!

If anyone has thoughts, suggestions, or even ideas of where to go from here it would be greatly appreciated.